# MFC one parent dialog, multiple child dialogs

Tags: c++, mfc

I want to build a MFC application, with one main dialog, and all the other dialogs are child of this main dialog (and embedded in it).

Now, i was able to embed the first child in the main dialog, but i want to pass to the next dialog (note that the order of opened dialogs is random), so i need to hide the first dialog and show another. To know which dialog is shown at the moment and hide it, i've tried using a `CDialog` variable to store the current opened dialog, but i get a `CObject::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'CObject'` error.

Is there another way to do this "hide and show dialogs" game?

EDIT: Could i store some ID of the dialogs and use it to acomplish this task?

Comment: Have you subclassed CDialog? Sounds almost as if you haven't

Comment: You should, then in the main dialog just add a vector with them e.g. std::vector<std::shared_ptr<CDialog>> to keep track of them. Whenever you move from one dialog to another go through the vector and show/hide

Comment: And just subclassing is going to be enough to store dialogs in a vector, or list? Isn't there some method to override or change?

Comment: If you at least subclass one dialog you can put in whatever members you want e.g. a vector of dialog pointers. then add a method to create all the dialogs hidden, after that it is just a matter of turning visibility on and off. you haven't explained so much in your question so i am just trying to answer from what you have asked.

Comment: Would a property sheet framework be more appropriate?

Comment: I managed to do it using dialogs' classes IDDs, but i don't really like this because i have to verify all the dialogs with `if clause`. I will post an answer with my code. @rrirower, please tell me more about using a property sheet, even post an answer if you are kind.

Comment: As requested, a [property sheet](http://www.functionx.com/visualc/dialogboxes/proppages.htm) provides the ability to add "pages".  In addition, you can construct a property  sheet in the form of a "wizard".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to accomplish this task using classes IDDs.

First, i store the last opened dialog's IDD

```
m_dlgStartPage.Create(CStartPageDlg::IDD, this);
m_openedWin.nDialogIDD = m_dlgStartPage.IDD;
m_dlgStartPage.ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
```

Then, when a new dialog needs to be shown, i send a message to my main dialog (`nIDD` is the IDD of pending dialog to show):

`AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd->SendMessage(WM_COMMAND_CHANGE_WINDOW, nIDD, 0);`

And last, in my main dialog, i parse all the child dialogs and check if `m_openedWin.nDialogIDD` matches with each dialog's IDD, so i can hide it. After this, i parse once again all the chid dialogs and use the `nIDD` from the sent message to show the correct one.

I don't really like this approach, because of all the parsing and sent messages to the main dialog's class, so if anyone has a better idea or method, please post it.